# Querying for a field inside another

Tags: mongodb, casbah, querying

I have got this document in `myDb.myCollection`:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55fc0ec8666292b85178c180"),
"firstname" : "george",
"surname" : "abitbol",
"data" : {
    "a" : "secret value",
    "b" : "4"
},
"tags" : "[t]"
```

How do I query for the `b` field in `data` to equal `"4"`?

I tried this:

```
val r = myCollection.find({"data.b" -> "4"})

for (d <- r)    
println (d)
```

But here is the error I get:

```
No implicit view available from (String, String) => com.mongodb.casbah.commons.TypeImports.DBObject.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import following statements-

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import com.mongodb.casbah.commons.MongoDBObject
```

And you should use query something like:

```
collection.find(MongoDBObject("data.a" -> "4"))
```